# AngularJS select options maintaining content after selection and resetting to blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the current code (I didn't write it just trying to work with it)-

```
<select type="text" id="{{for}}" name="{{for}}" ng-model="model.value" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-options="c.name as c.name for c in countries track by c.code">
  <option value="">— Select —</option>
</select>
```

and the countries array seems to be set up like so

```
$http.get('services/dictionary/countries').then(function(response) {
   _.chain(response.data).map(function(country) {
     return {
       code: country.id,
       digraph: country.digraph,
       trigraph: country.trigraph,
       name: country.name
     };
   }).sortBy('name').each(function(country) {
      dictionary.countries.push(country);
   });

   deferred.resolve(dictionary.countries);
}, function(error) {
    $log.error('dictionary:', error);
});
```

We are pulling the list of countries from some dictionary service, and trying to display them as select options. (we aren't really using digraph and trigraph here, but it's needed for other areas that use the same dictionary call).

Problem 1 is, we can set the choice and it saves, but the select list will not show the object I saved, especially after I store and refresh it.I assume this is because we aren't properly setting the value="" with the ng-options we've set up, but I can't get it to work properly after trying many iterations (don't really understand the documentation).

Problem 2 is, on this and all other select dropdowns we have, I can't figure out a way to revert to a null choice. I have a value="" default option but it doesn't blank out the ng-model when selected. we need this to allow for user screw ups, 'oops i didn't even mean to set that field.' type things.

Much appreciated for the help gang.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: Are you setting the ngModel value to the saved value on refresh? Only then will it be selected on the refresh.

Problem 2: Set the model to an empty object in your controller:
`model = {};`

Comment: Shouldn't be empty object because it's a string (set in a mongoose model). Yes of course it's being stored, it's odd because if the choice is 'United States' the model says 'United States' but the select box doesn't show like 'United States' was selected.

Comment: Can you post your controller? Maybe a Plunk?